# How to set a DateTime prop (DeletedTime) of Null by using annotion maybe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, annotations, swagger

I have DateTime property to check when the producet is created Or deleted, But when adding a product then DeletedTime has to be null or empty.
I know that DateTime is a value type so i could not use null or 0.

public DateTime DeletedTime {get;set} = null (did not work).
Also not: public DateTime DeletedTime {get;set} = DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: You can't set null to `DateTime` type. Unless you are using `DateTime?` which is nullable DateTime. `public DateTime? DeletedTime {get;set} = null`

Comment: public DateTime? DeletedTime { get; set; } = null; By this prop in post request is still time now, how can i set this in post request to null??

Comment: You can use the Nullable<T> `Nullable<DateTime> dateTime = DateTime.Now;
dateTime = null;`

Comment: For string i could use smothing like: public string ProductName {get;set;} = string.Empty;
And for DateTime???

Comment: Then like this `public Nullable<DateTime> dateTime { get; set; } = null;`

Comment: *how can i set this in post request to null* Either in your post request, you set the value as null `deletedTime: null`or don't include the`deletedTime` field in the request.

Comment: Note from the first comment, you don't need to assign `null` to `DeletedTime`: `public DateTime? DeletedTime {get;set}`. By default it will be `null`.

Comment: Then i got this: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]. Path: $[0].deletedTime | LineNumber: 8 | BytePositionInLine: 23."

Comment: @YongShun and how not include the DeletedTime prop in post request?

Comment: *how not include the DeletedTime prop* --> Just don't provide the `DeletedTime` property in the request. Please also provide how you submit the request to API.

Comment: For all request i use in controller the same model (Abstraction class Product) and it has CreationTime and DeletedTime so in post request i would like this props be null

Comment: If you want to not include one property in your request, you can set [JsonIgnore] attribute on that property, this attribute Prevents a property from being serialized or deserialized. Actually i still don't understand why you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the property like this

```
class Person
{
  public DateTime? DeleteDate {get;set;}
}
```

then you can set in code

```
Person person = new Person();
person.DeleteDate = null;
```

Comment: Thank you all guys, but the issue still not sovled! error fro entity framwork :
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details. Colum 'DeletedTime' cannot be null. So in Post request still i have to fill in the fiedl with time But it is no logic for a new product to has a DeletedTime with time now or whatever than null or empty!

Comment: But this is a error message from database engine and you have to set the table column to nullable....

Comment: Yeah it was an option to add this. thx

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testModel tm = new testModel();
        //tm.date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(tm.date);
    }
}

public class testModel{
    public DateTime? date {get; set;} = default;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I have solved by set a default value of dateTime in the database. And that accepting Null value. Thank you to make time for me.